# Is there a phrase that can replace "consists in part" when the part is about half?

Tags: phrase-requests

If I say that

> My job consists in part of scheduling meetings.

I understand that this is some relatively small part of the job. If instead I say something like

> My job consists in large part of scheduling meetings.
>
> My job consists mostly of scheduling meetings.

then I think the implication is that more than 50%, probably more like 60-70 is scheduling meetings. However, I want to be able to find a synonymous phrase for

> About half of my job is scheduling meetings.

but where I can start the sentence with "My job".

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common expression is

> My job is fifty percent scheduling meetings.

most people would expect in reality that its not literally half.

However they may expect you to explain the other half and thus if you were Theresa May you could pre-empt that by saying.

> My job is split fifty, fifty between scheduling meetings and running
>   the country.